# Need help understanding an error (F3 '(6 3 4 1)) is not a real number Lisp code

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

This is my lisp code. I’m trying to solve this problem:

> Define function f3 that takes a simple list of integers as an argument and returns the number (count) of integers
> in the list which are between -3 and +15 (-3 and +15 included). For example:
>
> ```
> LISP> (f3 '(1 -2 17 -4))
> 2
> ```

This is my take on the problem and I’m stuck.  I don't know what I’m doing wrong.

```
(defun f3 (x)
  (if (null x)
      0
    (if (>(car x) - 3) 
        (if (<(car x) 15)
            (+ 1(f3 (cdr x)))
          (f3 (cdr x))
          (f3 (cdr x))))))
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Whenever you find yourself writing nested `if` conditionals, consider using [cond](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough parentheses after the second `(f3 (cdr xx))`. As you can see when the code is properly indented, that puts the last 2 recursive calls inside the same `if`; the last one was supposed to be in the previous `if`.

But there's no need for separate `if` expressions for `-3` and `15`. You can combine the tests with `and`, or take advantage of the fact that it's the same comparison for both endpoints and use `(<= -3 (car x) 15)`. Note also that the question says that the endpoints are included, so you should use `<=` rather than `<`.

Finally, there shouldn't be a space between `-` and `3`. I suspect that was just a copying error, since you would have gotten a different error in that case.

```
(defun f3 (x)
  (if (null x)
      0
    (if (<=  -3 (car x) 15)
        (+ 1 (f3 (cdr x)))
      (f3 (cdr x)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp is a very mature language and as such it has a lot of practical stuff in its "standard-library". In your case, all you need is to use the function `count-if` and write the correct predicate.

```
(defun count-in-range (values)
       (count-if (lambda (x) (and (>= x -3) (<= x 15))) values))

;; (count-in-range '(1 -2 17 -4))
;; => 2
```